# Ruby on Rails Devise Security Extension session_limitable not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've followed the instructions on the devise security extension page, but I'm not able to get the session_limitable implemented correctly. Are there any settings within the devise.rb that need to be configured in order for it to work? I've added the :session_limitable to the user.rb along with the rest of the steps. Please let me know what you've done to get this to work. Thanks!

1. gem 'devise_security_extension'
2. rails generate devise_security_extension:install
3. Added :session_limitable to my users.rb
4. Added unique_session_id to Users:
   class AddSessionLimitableToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       add_column :users, :unique_session_id, :string, :limit => 20
     end
   end
5. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have added :session_limitable to the model you want to use this with.

Comment: I did that but when I tried logging in from one chrome window and another incognito and it let me log in.

Comment: just let me know the steps you have taken so far

Comment: also confirm you have ```t.string :unique_session_id, :limit => 20``` in the model you want to use it with

Comment: I just updated the description with what I've done so far.

Comment: Alright seems you've done everything could your try a session from another browser and see if that works

Comment: Tried opening my development environment in safari and it still let me in using the same email (user id).

Comment: On some of my rails projects I use it's more frequently updated fork devise security https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security. Maybe you can give this a run

Comment: Also what the gem is supposed to do is kill/invalidate the previous session not deny you login/prevent login so can you check your are still able to use your previous sessions

Comment: Bingo! Thanks so much for your help. That gem definitely works better.